# Elegantly Assign Variables of Unknown Length

Tags: python

(Sorry. The title's pretty unclear. I couldn't come up with a good one.)

Say I have a url like so (it's root-relative):

```
"/forums/support/windows/help_i_deleted_sys32/6/"
```

and I'm trying to split this into a class structure like this:

```
class Forum_Spot:
    def __init__(self, url):
        parts = url.strip("/").split("/")
        #parts is now ["forums", "support", "windows", "help...", "6"]

        self.root = "forums"
        self.section = "support"
        self.subsection = "windows"
        self.thread = "help..."
        self.post = "6"
```

but say I don't know how long exactly the url will be (it could be "/forums/support/", "/forums/support/windows/", etc) (but I do know it won't be any deeper than 5 levels). Can anybody think of an elegant way to assign these values, letting any parts not assigned be `None`? (I.e. for "/forums/support/windows/", the thread and post attributes would be None)

I know I could do this:

```
class Forum_Spot:
    def __init__(self, url):
        parts = url.strip("/").split("/")
        #parts is now ["forums", "support", "windows", "help...", "6"]

        if len(parts) > 0:
            self.root = parts[0]
        else:
            self.root = None
        if len(parts) > 1:
            self.section = parts[1]
        else:
            #etc
```

but this is obviously superinelegant and obnoxiously labor-intensive. Can anybody think of a more elegant solution, keeping the class signature the same? (I could convert the `__init__` function to take keyword parameters, defaulting to `None`, but I'd like to be able to just pass in the url and have the class figure it out on its own)

Thanks!

Comment: will the order of the levels always be the same?

Comment: Yes.___________________

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use sequence unpacking:

```
>>> strs =  "/forums/support/"
>>> spl =strs.strip('/').split('/')
>>> a,b,c,d,e = spl + [None]*(5-len(spl))
>>> a,b,c,d,e
('forums', 'support', None, None, None)

>>> strs = "/forums/support/windows/"
>>> spl =strs.strip('/').split('/')
>>> a,b,c,d,e = spl + [None]*(5-len(spl))
>>> a,b,c,d,e
('forums', 'support', 'windows', None, None)

>>> strs = "/forums/support/windows/help_i_deleted_sys32/6/"
>>> spl =strs.strip('/').split('/')
>>> a,b,c,d,e = spl + [None]*(5-len(spl))
>>> a,b,c,d,e
('forums', 'support', 'windows', 'help_i_deleted_sys32', '6')
```

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! I thought tuple unpacking might be helpful here, but I wasn't clever enough to figure it out. : (    Thanks a kajillion! (Will accept the answer as soon as SO lets me)

Comment: You could just use a list too. Instead of making 5 different variables. :)

Comment: I want to refer to them by name though. That's why I'm creating a class in the first place.

Comment: @SukritKalra OP wants to assign those values to variables.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a setter method to your class that sets appropriate default values:

```
class Forum_Spot:
    def __init__(self, url):
        parts = url.split('/')[1:]
        # use function argument unpacking:
        self.set_url(*parts)

    def set_url(self, root, section=None, subsection=None, thread=None, post=None):
        self.root = root
        self.section = section
        self.subsection = subsection
        self.thread = thread
        self.post = post
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `itertools.izip_longest` (renamed to `zip_longest` in Python 3) to build a dictionary by creating `name, value` tuples, with `None` filling in for any missing values:

```
import itertools

names = ["root", "section", "subsection", "thread", "post"]
values = url.strip("/").split("/")

name_value_dict = dict(itertools.izip_longest(names, values))
```

Now you can either use the dictionary directly, of if you need to create member variables on an object, you can use `dict.update` to merge it into an existing dictionary:

```
self.__dict__.update(name_value_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

A fancier method than moooeeeep's would be to use a `namedtuple`. (Or rather, a subclass of one with default values.)

```
from collections import namedtuple

class _Path(namedtuple('Path', 'root section subsection thread post')):
    def __new__(cls, root=None, section=None, subsection=None, thread=None, post=None):
        # add default values
        return super(_Path, cls).__new__(cls, root, section, subsection, thread, post)

Path = lambda s: _Path(*s.strip('/').split('/'))
```

And then...

```
>>> Path("/forums/support/")
_Path(root='forums', section='support', subsection=None, thread=None, post=None)
```